# Definite integral of general polylogarithm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

$$\int_{0}^{1} Li_k(x) dx$$

$$Li_k(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^k}$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} Li_k(x) \,dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{n^k} \,dx$$

From Fubini's theorem, I suppose we were allowed to interchange.

$$\int_{0}^{1} Li_k(x) \,dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)n^k}]_{0}^{1}$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} Li_k(x) \,dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^k}$$

Let $$S = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^k}$$

I am having the big trouble in evaluating the sum $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $$S_k := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^k},\quad k=1,2,3,\ldots.$$
Observe that, for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
S_{k+1} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^{k+1}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)-n}{(n+1)n^{k+1}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{k+1}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^k}\\
&= \zeta(k+1)-S_{k+1} \tag1
\end{align}
$$ where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function.

Rewrite $(1)$ as 
$$
(-1)^{k+1}S_{k+1}-(-1)^{k}S_{k}=(-1)^{k+1}\zeta(k+1) \tag2
$$ sum $(2)$ from $k=1$ to $k=p-1$, $p=2,3,4,\ldots$,  then, by telescoping terms, you get

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)n^p}=(-1)^{p-1}+\sum_{k=2}^{p}(-1)^{p-k}\zeta(k), \quad p=1,2,3,\ldots.
> $$

where, by a direct telescoping, using $\displaystyle
\frac{1}{(n+1)n}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)}$, we have obtained $\displaystyle
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)n}=1$ .